# Cannot retrieve body text along with upload, Express js

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I have a form that asks for a text and a file. I use multer for the file upload. The problem is I cannot retrieve the text with `req.body` if i use `enctype=multipart/form-data`

**Route file**

```
router.post('/new-job', function(req,res,next){
  upload(req,res,function(err) {
   if(err) {
      return res.end("Error uploading file.");
   }
  });

  var newJob = {
    job_name: req.body.job_name, //Cannot retrieve this two
    job_desc: req.body.job_desc, 
  };

  var newJobData = new Jobs(newJob);
  newJobData.save(function(err,user){
  if(err)
    console.log(err);
  });

  res.render('jobs/new-job', {job_added:true});
});
```

**Multer configs**

```
var multer = require('multer');
var  storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, 'public/uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.originalname);
  }
});
```

Notes

- I used method post
- If i log the `req.body.job_name` it returns an undefined
- If i remove the `enctype=multipart/form-data` i can retrieve the text just fine, though i cannot upload the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access `req.body` contents until you're parsed the request, so either move your code inside your `upload()` callback, *or* get rid of the explicit `upload()` call entirely and just put `upload` before your route handler:

```
router.post('/new-job', upload, function(req, res, next) {
  var newJob = {
  // ...
```

Comment: I did not know I was missing such simple thing, thank you @mscdex